# Mono.Data.Sqlite.dll compatibility with SQLite.Net

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I built the core logic for my app using a console application in Visual Studio using SQLite.Net, I thought I was simply going to be able to switch out the using statement from

```
using System.Data.SQLite;
```

to

```
using Mono.Data.Sqlite.dll
```

This process has worked perfectly for other components (Json.Net for example).

However I am finding casing differences between the two Sqlite dll's (SQL and Sql).

**System.Data.SQLite**

```
SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, DbConnection);
SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

**Mono.Data.Sqlite**

```
SqliteCommand command = new SqliteCommand(sql, DbConnection);
SqliteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

Its easy enough to correct with a global find and replace but its a bit annoying each time I switch between environments to have to do so. Can anyone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this by using a second class to abstract the database calls. I have two assemblies containing platform specific versions of a `SQLQuery` class, one for windows projects and one for monotouch.

My database layer just calls `SQLQuery` so my calls are something like

```
SQLQuery q = new SQLQuery("SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar = @bar");
q.AddParameter("bar", bar);
DataTable dt = q.GetResultsDT();
```

and this will work on either platform, as long as the `SQLQuery` assembly for that platform is referenced in the project.

Answer (score 1):

One way to get around this is to define a project constant, and then use `#if` blocks.

Your using:

```
#if MONO_SQLITE
using Mono.Data.Sqlite.dll
#else
using System.Data.SQLite;
#endif
```

Your code:

```
#if MONO_SQLITE
    SqliteCommand command = new SqliteCommand(sql, DbConnection);
    SqliteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(); 
#else
    SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, DbConnection);
    SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
#endif
```

Depending on whether you are using Mono or the .Net stack, you then just add or remove the `MONO_SQLITE` constant definition from your project.

The Mono C# compiler also defines the symbol `__MonoCS__`. I don't know if MonoTouch does so, but if it did you could also do:

```
#if __MonoCS__
// ... mono stuff
#else
// ... MS stuff
#endif
```

Comment: I think is far better to use an abstraction layer (ie. factory pattern) to avoid this.